# How to fetch Sqlite records using three different strings

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to fetch records using three different strings.
for example:i have stored three columns like first name,middle name,last name
now if user entered first name or middle name or last name in Edittext.
records should be fetched.

I have tried using "OR" but m not getting the expected result.

Comment: post the sql command you used.

Comment: Please provide more information, including some of the SQL you have tried. Do all three names need to be provided? Are partial names acceptable? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use LIKE.

Check this out:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_like_clause.htm

Answer (score 0):

This sql statement should work for you:
`SELECT * FROM ATable where ItemA > 2 OR ItemB > 1 OR ItenC < 1.00;`

Comment: what is 2,1 here ??i want like if user full name is abc cde efg...and if he enter abc or cde or efg the details of that user should be fetched

Comment: It is an example!     If you want to use text, where ItemA = "abc"

Comment: You mean: `where ItemA = 'abc'`

Comment: My version of sqlite3 accepts either single or double quotes, so no I didn't mean 'abc', but I could have used it rather than "abc", as both would be correct